# pivot tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

**Have a table data as:**

```
 d1  d2  MON REPORT_DATE   

 67 46  Dec 2014-12-19 06:19:05.337

 69 46  Dec 2014-12-22 06:21:47.430

 67 85  Jan 2015-01-23 06:08:09.030
```

**I need a result set as**

```
      DEC  JAN
D1    69    67

D2    46    85
```

So far

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT PerValueStreamOnAutoDiags,
              PerProdSupportOnAutoDiags,
              LEFT(Datename(Month, ReportDate), 3)[Month],
              ReportDate
       FROM   Temp_AutoApprovalMembercnt)AS s
      PIVOT ( Max(ReportDate)
            FOR [month] IN (dec,
                            jan) )AS p
```

Comment: select *  from(select d1
,d2
,Left(DATENAME(Mon,ReportDate),3)[Month],ReportDate from T1)as s
pivot
(
 max(ReportDate) for [month] in (dec,jan)
)as p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
;with cte as
(select * from 
 (select PerValueStreamOnAutoDiags,
          PerProdSupportOnAutoDiags,
          LEFT(Datename(Month, ReportDate), 3)[Month] 
  from Temp_AutoApprovalMembercnt) as s
 unpivot
 (val
  for cols in (PerValueStreamOnAutoDiags,PerValueStreamOnAutoDiags)) as u)

select * from
(select * from cte) as s
pivot
(max(val)
 for [Month] in (DEC,JAN)) as p
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IJUH63724)

First **unpivot** the data to bring `PerValueStreamOnAutoDiags` and `PerProdSupportOnAutoDiags` into rows from columns, and then pivot to get the data summarised by the month.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data *and* reaggregate it, because you are swapping rows and columns.  Here is a method using aggregation and `union all`:

```
select 'd1' as col, max(case when mon = 'Dec' then d1 end) as dec,
       max(case when mon = 'Jan' then d1 end) as Jan
from Temp_AutoApprovalMembercnt
union all 
select 'd2' as col, max(case when mon = 'Dec' then d2 end) as dec,
       max(case when mon = 'Jan' then d2 end) as Jan
from Temp_AutoApprovalMembercnt;
```